# Need to understand Python generator object

Tags: python, generator, generator-expression

In the following:

```
name = 'TODD'
chars = set('AEIOU')
for ii in range(-1, int(math.copysign(len(name) + 1, -1)), -1):
    if any((cc in chars) for cc in name[ii]):
        print 'Found'
    else:
        print 'Not Found'
```

I understand that what's inside any(...) is a generator object.  What I don't understand is the lack of parentheses - if the parentheses belong to the any() function, shouldn't there be another set of parentheses around the generator expression?

Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The parenthesis can be omitted when used in function calls with only one argument, the [generator expression syntax](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions) specifically allows for it.

> The parentheses can be omitted on calls with only one argument. See section [Calls](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#calls) for the detail.

Comment: I don't think you pasted the link you meant to.

Comment: @interjay: good catch, c&p failure. Anyone else enjoy set-lists of Norwegian festival concerts? :-P Corrected.

Answer (score 2):

You can leave out the parentheses of a generator expression if the expression is the only thing in parentheses already.

From the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions):

> The parentheses can be omitted on calls with only one argument.

Answer (score 2):

No, the extra parens are not needed, nor in fact are parens always necessary for the "Boolean expression" you are testing, see these two simple examples:

```
In [37]: any(i > 10 for i in range(19))
Out[37]: True

In [38]: all(i > 10 for i in range(19))
Out[38]: False
```

What you have is a function call with a single argument (your generator expression) so no parens are required. See the [generator expressions docs](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions) for more information.

Comment: doesn't really answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

For function calls with just one argument (that generator expression), they aren't required per the [docs](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions)

> The parentheses can be omitted on calls with only one argument. See section Calls for the detail.